# AWS CloudFormation error: [Value of property {/Tags/0/Values} does not match type {Map}]

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to add tags to an aws resource in a cloudformation template.

```
          "Type" : "AWS::MediaLive::resource",
    "Properties" : {
        "Name" : {"Ref": "name"},
        "RoleArn" : {"Ref": "RoleArn"},
         "Tags" : {"Key": "projectName", "Value":"myProject}


      }
```

I get the error that the tags is not in "Map" format.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A map format in CloudFormation relies on reference to an existing parameter. So in my template, I had to create a parameter for my project key/value:

```
"Parameters: {
"projectName": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "myProject"

      }
```

Then, in your resource, you can add the tag by using "Ref" to the parameter above:

```
 "Type" : "AWS::MediaLive::resource",
    "Properties" : {
        "Name" : {"Ref": "name"},
        "RoleArn" : {"Ref": "RoleArn"},
         "Tags" : {"projectName": {"Ref": "projectName"}}

      }
```

In essence what will happen is that CF will take the "Key" from the parameter declaration, in this case "projectName", and then get the "Value" from the default value in the parameter above, which will be "myProject".